# Copying SUMIF exact date +1d formula

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I should be able to do this but my brain has stopped working again. I'm working on a google sheet at work. I want to copy a simple formula to the cells below, increasing the exact date by one day to the rows below. I put this formula in P2

```
=SUMIF(Zapv1SUP!$S$2:$S,DATE(2016, 10, 1),Zapv1SUP!$V$2:$V)
```

How can I increase the date by one date when copying the formula, so it's like this in P3 and P4 etc etc...

```
=SUMIF(Zapv1SUP!$S$2:$S,DATE(2016, 10, 1) +1,Zapv1SUP!$V$2:$V)
=SUMIF(Zapv1SUP!$S$2:$S,DATE(2016, 10, 1) +2,Zapv1SUP!$V$2:$V)
```

Something tells me I should be using INDIRECT, but I don't know.

I'm trying to create an a sheet to total up bookings we've taken for the future.

Thanks for any help.

I included the Excel tag as it's also relevant there too I guess.

Comment: in Excel:   `+ROWS($1:1)` will increment by one for each row.

Comment: Thanks penus, noted.

Comment: Thanks Ron, appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ron Rosenfeld's suggestions also works in Google Sheets i.e. in P3 put

```
=SUMIF(Zapv1SUP!$S$2:$S,DATE(2016, 10, 1)+rows($1:1),Zapv1SUP!$V$2:$V)
```